# Configure Laravel project on a DSO handler server

Tags: php, configuration, laravel-5, handler

I have a Laravel 5.0 project that I want to test on servers that supports different php handler like:-

```
1.  suPHP (Single user PHP)
2.  FCGI (FastCGI)
3.  CGI (Common Gateway Interface)
4.  DSO (Dynamic Shared Object)
```

In case of first three the project works fine.

And also I tried to move the project out of public.

But when ever I try to run the project on a DSO server it fails.

There is just:-

```
1.  Mozila -> blank screen
2.  Chrome -> 500 error
```

The server I have is a VPS Linux server.

And I was just changing the php handlers.

For the first three case the php handler API is CGI

and For the DSO its Apache

Please let me know what would be the appropriate solution.

This is my error log

```
 [Fri Nov 06 11:46:20.789176 2015] [:error] [pid 1111] [client 111.111.111.111:11111] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/home/site-name/public_html/project-name/code/storage/logs/laravel-2015-11-06.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /home/site-name/public_html/project-name/code/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/site-name/public_html/project-name/code/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php(88): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /home/site-name/public_html/project-name/code/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\RotatingFileHandler->write(Array)\n#2 /home/site-name/public_html/project-name/code/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#3 /home/site-name/public_html/project-name/code/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php in /home/site-name/public_html/project-name/code/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 87
```

Thank You

Comment: please post server error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its just today I found the solution.

On a DSO server the file or folder permission should be set to 777 on the server.

And the exact path that gets affected due to this is Laravel-project/storage folder should have the 777 file permission. And also all the folders and files within it and more within.